# Rails Savon SOAP Authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, soap, savon

I am developing on Rails 3 and using Savon(savonrb.com)

1. I need to connect to Web Services via SOAP
2. Web Services require authentication

I can connect but can't get authonticated...

I used SOAP UI for testing & all works fine.

Here how my Rails code looks like:

```
client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.document = "http://services.blahblah.com/Service.asmx?WSDL"
end

client.wsse.credentials "username", "password", :digest

if response.success?

  @soap_status = 'Connected'
  @data = response.to_array(:get_brochure_response, :error_message)

end
```

I get response but :error_message returns Authentication failed...

Here is how it looks in SOAP UI

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://services.blahblah.com/service">
   <soap:Header>
      <ser:ICEAuthHeader>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:Username>username</ser:Username>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:Password>password</ser:Password>
      </ser:ICEAuthHeader>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <ser:GetBrochure>
    <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:MappedID>123</ser:MappedID>
      </ser:GetBrochure>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I've never used Savon, but have used soap, i've seen some cases where the server really done's like comments, is there a way that you can remove the <!--Optional:--> to test without those? Also are there any errors you are getting back? Like the SOAP response?

Comment: I am not passing the SOAP code, I have just puten it here as example so it's more understandable. I can connect to SOAP & getting responce back. But unauthenticated response. I have tried many ways to pass username & password but does not seem to work...

Comment: Are you sure of the authentication method? Is there maybe a basic auth? Or is there maybe authentication on server level?

Answer (score 1):

Are the username and password sent with the SOAP request in the headers? If so, you could go about doing this when initializing the Savon client (see [cannot set SOAP header parameters on savon call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466054/cannot-set-soap-header-parameters-on-savon-call)):

```
client = Savon.client(
    wsdl: SOAP_WSDL,
    endpoint: SOAP_URL,
    soap_header: { :username => username, :password => password }
)
```

Incidentally, if only certain calls need authentication, you can make calls like so:

```
response = client.call(
    :soap_call,
    :soap_header => { :username => username, :password => password },
    message: {message}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this to authenticate using basic auth:

```
client = Savon::Client.new do
  wsdl.document = "http://services.blahblah.com/Service.asmx?WSDL"
  http.auth.basic "username", "password"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
client = Savon.client( wsdl: 'http://service.example.com?wsdl',soap_header: { "AuthenticateRequest" => {"apiKey" => "****** your api *********"}}, pretty_print_xml: true)

client.operations

response = client.call(:function)
```

## here "apiKey" is my prams to authenticate api, your can be different